# Python app on widows to LwIP echo server on Zynq fails if socket closed and new one opened

Tags: python, sockets, arm, lwip, zynq

I have a python application running on a win7 pc. It connects to a TCP/IP "echo" server running as a bare metal application on a Zynq (Arm core 0).
The python application comes up, opens a socket and exchanges data with the echo application (which is modified to return useful information depending on the string from the PC).  If the python application is closed, and then re-opened. All is fine. The new socket is used correctly.  But if the python application does not close, but keeps running and decides to close the socket that's opened to the ZYnq, and then decides to open a new socket with the ZYnq, problems occur. I make sure that the Python socket is closed (even tried "shutdown()" before closing).  There seems to be something lingering in the LwIP on the server side (could be in the Xilinx lib written to use LwIP).  Using the second socket from the PC side is unreliable.  Strange delays occurs inside the ZYnq application. The work around is to shut down the Python application entirely.

I've noticed one difference between shutting down the Python application and closing the socket while the Python app is still running: when closing the socket from a running Python application under Win7, the recv_callback() function registered to run in the echo application on the Zynq is called with a null pointer. That's the only time recv_callback() is called with a null pointer. I don't know if this is significant.  For the time being, I will prevent a user from closing a connection from the running Python application, and will instead force the user to close the application to properly close the connection (or to properly reset something in the LwIP lib).